# php artisan queue not showing anything

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.0 and trying to set a queue for sending an email, I have created it and wrote code like.
`Queue::pushOn('emails', new SendEmail($user));`
It's adding a row in the jobs table, then I'm running the following command

`$ php artisan queue:listen`

But it is not showing anything and not sending emails too.

Comment: Do you have `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` in .env file?

Comment: yes
@IndianCoding

Answer (score 0):

Check out that you have in `config/queue.php` a connection with the name of `emails` because you are pushing to this `queue` with the method `pushOn()`.
As a alternative, only push in the default `queue` using:

```php
Queue::push(new SendEmail($user));
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to try to:

```
config:clear
cache:clear
config:cache
```

And then:

```
php artisan queue:listen emails
```

Will listen for jobs in the emails queue.

Answer (score 0):

Hay, I had this same issue,
I had an error in my job code that's why it's stuck in queue:listen , to make sure there is no error in your job code.

you can put the following check in job handle() methfor the error.

```
public function handle()
{
  try{
   // your code here.
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
      dd($e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

then run.

> $ php artisan queue:listen emails

Now, if there is an error in your code the error will display in the command line.
Hope this can help you.